# Finetune google sheets script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, time, automation

I need to fine tune the script, [0] is clients name, [5] are expiry dates, [6] my mail.
The script should automatically check every day at 8 am, and send auto mails if something is expired.
The mail should be sent 15 days before expiry date [5], and should be sent only 1 time when reach expiry.
With this seems to work with no errors, but something isn't right.
Thank you for your help

```js
function alertSender() {
  var today = new Date();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(r => r[0] != '');
    for (n = 1; n < values.length; ++n) {
      var cell_date = values[n][5];
      var expired = (cell_date - 15 * 86400000) > today;
      if (expired) {
        MailApp.sendEmail(values[n][6], 'Mail automatica scadenza', 'Polizza scaduta per il sig. ' + values[n][0]);
        Logger.log('Mail inviata all\'indirizzo ' + values[n][6] + ' del sig. ' + values[n][0]);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: hope there is no mistakes this time. I have tested it. Please, do not forget to add a title on column H.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the issue you are having? What is not working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "SENT" on cell H1 of each tab. Colmn H will receive the date of email sending. This date will be tested to prevent recurrences.

Try

```
function alertSender() {
  var today = new Date();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
    values.forEach(r => {
      if (r[0] != '' && r[7] == '') {
        var cell_date = new Date(r[5]);
        var expired = (cell_date <= new Date(today.getTime() + 15 * 86400000));
        if (expired) {
          MailApp.sendEmail(r[6], 'Mail automatica', 'Servizio scaduto per il sig. ' + r[0]);
          Logger.log('Mail inviata all\'indirizzo ' + r[6] + ' del sig. ' + r[0]);
          r[7] = Utilities.formatDate(today, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
        }
      }
    })
    sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values)
  })
}
```

to get the exact date, you can try

```
var expired = (cell_date.valueOf() == new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + 15).valueOf())
```

Comment: Is working perfect with the column H for dates, wich is usefull too. But something is off with the dates, it sends just for anyone or for noone. For example, it must send if there are 15 days to expiry: Expiry 20/07/22 should send today, expiry 30/07 should send 15/07.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I posted a complement. However, if you change the lead time, or if you have a problem with the trigger one day, you could miss sending email. It's why I prefer the first solution. Of course at the very beginning you will send all the backlog (you can prevent it by filling X in column H for old items) but once everything has been done, you will fetch the exacts items. However I hope to answer your requirement.

Comment: New Expired var works just perfect, thank you very much.